# Performing a For... Next copy paste action in a macro that looks in a range returns Run-time error '1004' if there is only one entry in the range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that looks in a range and creates a copy of a sheet for each entry in the range.  Additionally, within the macro is the action that determines which sheet should be copied based on information in an adjacent cell.  Problem is, when there is only one entry in the range, which starts at F13, a Run-time error '1004' results.  When I have data in F13 and F14 there is no error and the sheets are created with out error.  Tried several stop ifs but with no luck.  The portion of the code that gives and error with one entry and no errors with two or more entries in the range is shown below.  Is there a simple solution to this or is a differnt more complex model needed.  When debugging the 'Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = mycell.Value' is highlighted.

```
With Sheets("ProjectDefinition")
    For Each myCell In .Range(.Range("f13"), .Range("f13").End(xlDown))

        myCell.Value = "{" & myCell.Value & "}"

        Select Case UCase(myCell.Offset(0, -4))
            Case "S"
                strWSname = "MasterReport2"
            Case "P"
                strWSname = "MasterReport"
            Case Else
                strWSname = "MasterReport"   'default
        End Select

        Sheets(strWSname).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)  'Copies Tabs
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = myCell.Value   'Renames the new worksheet

        'Copies Part Number Into A1 On Report Tab'
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = myCell.Value

    Next myCell
End With`
```

Some sample data starting from F13:F15

```
45634567AB_extrsuion
45634567AB_form
45634567AB
```

Comment: If there's nothing below F13, the range extends to the bottom of the sheet. That could cause problems. If that's the situation, consider doing xlUp from the last row instead.

Comment: findwindow - I Replaced code with ' For Each myCell In .Range(.Range("f13"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "f").End(xlUp).Row)'  and the same Run Time Error is returned.  This time the error shows even with multiple entries.  Information that may matter is that the range for the data is defined by F13:F62.

Comment: My fault. Drop `row` from the end. Edit: `For Each myCell In .Range(.Range("f13"), .Cells(.Rows.count, "f").End(xlUp))`

Comment: findwindow - Routine ran with some success but a new Run Time Error with the addtion of  "That name is already taken. Try a different one" is returned.   When debugging, the 'Sheets (Sheets.Count). Name = mycell.Value' is again highlighted.  It appears as if the macro coninutes through it's third Next item and sees a repeating nameless sheet.  Run Time Error returns again even with mulitple entries.

Comment: `myCell` can't repeat.

Comment: Understood.  The dedicted range between F13:F62 is where the user enters parts numbers from top to bottom.  There may be anywhere from 1 to 50 part numbers.  The orignal code using 'x1down' had no errors when entering anywhere from 2 to 50 part numbers.  Even stopping at 3 leaving from 4 to 50 empty their was no error and no duplication issues related  'myCell'.  Having only data in F13 was the issue.  Now when using x1Up it is the same Run Time Error is presented under all entry variations which is "The name is already taken".

Comment: Some sample data would help.

Comment: 'f13 - 45634567AB_extrsuion
'f14 - 45634567AB_form
'f15 - 45634567AB

Comment: Those 3 samples worked for me. Edit: my `case` is always `else` but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: The following are actual data in a sheet the works. 'F13= 45634567AB_extrsuion, F14 = 45634567AB_form, F15 - 45634567AB.  When the Macro is ran, three sheets are copied from an existing sheet called MasterReport.  The new sheet is renamed during the process to reflect the data in the cell.  If cells F14 and below are empty, the Run Time Error returns.  If there is a better way to communicate actual data, I am open for communicating correctly within the comments.

Comment: Having data in only cell F13 is when the error is returned.

Comment: The only time it breaks is if the name is already used! As I said above you can't repeat. Not sure what else to say/do. I tried my best. Good luck ^_^

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate your time and input.  I will continue to rework based on your comments.  There is always a solution.

Comment: You may want to look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37426597/excel-adding-worksheets/37429972#37429972) for some worksheet name duplicate  handling techniques

Comment: @user3598756 - Reviewed you recommended conversation and was able to modify code and eliminate all errors.  Used 'x1Down' and added the 'If Not myCell.Value = vbNullString Then'. This forced the end of the loop if data was not present in the range which then eliminated the duplication of a blank cell.  Thank you for the guidance.

Comment: you are welcome. glad you made it

Comment: @user3598756 - I noticed the check mark to select for question being answered is not visible.  Maybe things have changed.  Can you tell me how to show this as closed?

Comment: I think that since there has been no answers but only comments then you cannot close it. but I'm not that sure. try reading guides