# Loop to AutoFilter and evaluate specific criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a project that:

1. AutoFilters data by employee name from one workbook (raw data report)
2. Pastes the results of of that AutoFilter into another WB in a worksheet that shares that employee's name so further analysis can be done specific to that individual

I am not sure if the formatting for the raw data report is going to be consistent, so I likely need to make adjustments to my code in the future. I need some kind of loop that will make this process run more efficiently.

Note: this process will have to be repeated up to 200 times to account for each employee, see code below..

```
Dim sourceWB As Workbook
Dim destWB As Workbook

Set sourceWB = ThisWorkbook

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\users\andrew.godish\Desktop\ChadAT&T\CSCO Separated Data.xlsm"
Set destWB = ActiveWorkbook

'Code that needs to be Repeated
sourceWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:K1").AutoFilter Field:=2,   Criteria1:="Employee 1"
sourceWB.Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Range.Copy Destination:=destWB.Sheets("Employee 1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

ActiveCell.Columns("A:P").EntireColumn.Select
ActiveCell.Columns("A:P").EntireColumn.EntireColumn.AutoFit

If sourceWB.Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode Then  sourceWB.Sheets("Sheet1").ShowAllData

'Code that needs to be Repeated
sourceWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:K1").AutoFilter Field:=2,  Criteria1:="Employee 2"
sourceWB.Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Range.Copy Destination:=destWB.Sheets("Employee 2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

ActiveCell.Columns("A:P").EntireColumn.Select
ActiveCell.Columns("A:P").EntireColumn.EntireColumn.AutoFit

If sourceWB.Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode Then  sourceWB.Sheets("Sheet1").ShowAllData

'Code that needs to be Repeated
sourceWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:K1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Employee 3"
  sourceWB.Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Range.Copy   Destination:=destWB.Sheets("Employee 3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

ActiveCell.Columns("A:P").EntireColumn.Select
ActiveCell.Columns("A:P").EntireColumn.EntireColumn.AutoFit

If sourceWB.Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode Then sourceWB.Sheets("Sheet1").ShowAllData
```

So, as you can see, going through and editing out up to 200 of these repeated sections of code isn't really an option. I know I need some kind of loop, I'm thinking a For-Next Loop, but I am relatively new to VBA, and I can't wrap my head around what exactly needs to become my looping variables to make this work. Thanks all!

Comment: Looks like a FOR loop with an array of values to use as `Criteria1` (which can also be reused for `Destination := destWB.Sheets()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

Dim sourceWB As Workbook
Dim destWB As Workbook
Dim dataRng As Range, employeesRng As Range, cell As Range

Set sourceWB = ThisWorkbook

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\users\andrew.godish\Desktop\ChadAT&T\CSCO Separated Data.xlsm"
Set destWB = ActiveWorkbook

Set dataRng = sourceWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:K1") '<~~ set your range with data, headers included
Set employeesRng = sourceWB.Sheets("Employees").Range("A:A") '<~~ set your range with employees to process. I thought of names in column A of an "Empolyees" sheet of ThisWorkbook

employeesRng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes '<~~ get rid of employeess name duplicates

With dataRng
    For Each cell In employeesRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues) '<~~ loop through actual valid employees names in the empolyees range (no dupes and no blanks)
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=cell.Value
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then '<~~ check if there are any filtered values (headers are always there, so look for at least 2 values)
            .Parent.AutoFilter.Range.Copy Destination:=destWB.Sheets(cell.Value).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
            destWB.Sheets(cell.Value).Columns("A:P").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End If
        .AutoFilter
    Next cell
End With

End Sub
```

of course you must be sure that `destWB` has already one sheet per each employee name

otherwise you must implement a sheet presence handling technique like you may get [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37426597/excel-adding-worksheets/37429972#37429972)

Comment: Can you please explain to me the line of code reading:.... 

      If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then. .... 

I am not familiar with the Range.Subtotal() method...What are the arguments telling me exactly?

Comment: The Subtotal method of WorksheetFunction object can do many different countings you "choose" with its first parameter. With this latter passed as 103 and a Range object passed as its second parameter you get back the counting of visible cells in that Range

Comment: @AndyG did you get trough it?

Comment: I did, thank you. It took me a while to figure out a couple lines, but it works well. Thanks for the info.